# Conditional <exec> based on results of <copy>

Tags: nant

In our nant build script for our web-based application, we `<copy>` a set of files to a target directory and then run aspnet_compiler over them via `<exec>`.

`<copy>` only copies files that have changed, however here is no way to pass this information to `<exec>`, and I want to avoid running aspnet_compiler when nothing has actually changed.

Options I've tried to find are: `<copy>` setting a property when any file is copied that can then be checked with `<if>`; or being able to create a file before the copy and doing something like `<if test="any-file-newer-than(targetdir, timestampfile)">`. Even better would be if `<copy>` could return a list of copied files that I can then iterate over to avoid having to process the entire tree, but I think that might be asking a bit too much.

So far, I've drawn a blank: is what I'm looking for possible without writing a custom extension?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just simply replace copy task with robocopy? (you're on Windows, right?)

Robocopy returns different exit codes on different successful copy situations:
https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy-exit.html

For example:

- 0 - ok, nothing copied
- 1 - ok, something copied

You could do something like this:

```html
<exec program="robocopy.exe" commandline="${SourceDir} ${DestDir}" failonerror="false" resultproperty="ExitCode" />
<fail unless="${ExitCode &lt; 8}" message="Failed to copy"/> <!-- Anything between 0..7 is OK for robocopy -->
<exec unless="${ExitCode == 0}" ...
```